# How does alcohol infusion (maceration) work chemically?

Tags: alcohols, food-chemistry

To make liqueurs (e.g. lemon liqueur) you take some fruit and/or plant and let them macerate in pure alcohol to make the alcohol have the fragrance and color of the original ingredient.
How does it work from a chemical standpoint?
Is it simply a process in which the aromatic substances are soluble in alcohol and so the solution inherits their characteristics, or are there (as I expect) more complicated processes at work?

Comment: There are more complicated processes at work (as you expect), but you are correct in that the aromatic (and other) substances are soluble in the alcohol and thus are EXTRACTED by the alcohol. This is simply an extraction process.